# ButtonDown and ButtonUp events for Android screen buttons?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get an onButtonDown or onButtonUp event for a soft button (i.e. not a physical hardware button, but a button on the screen)?  I have a button on the screen that I want the user to hold down for X seconds.  To do this I need to capture the buttonDown and buttonUp events separately.

Thanks,

Bret

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
yourButton.setOnTouchListener( yourListener );

public boolean onTouch( View yourButton , MotionEvent theMotion ) {
    switch ( theMotion.getAction() ) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks, drawnonward!  I went in the direction of onLongClick since it seemed most intuitive (I was wrong) ;-).  I tried to upvote this, but I'm new here and don't have enough reputation points.  Thanks again!

Comment: Better also check MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL for "Up" since you could slide off the button and miss the "UP" action.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin variant

```
button.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {   }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP   -> {   }
            }
            return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
        }
    })
```