# how can i detect when a button is clicked but not released in android

Tags: java, android, button

I'm searching for a way to find out how to change the color of a button in android by using java code when the button is clicked but not released,I would be glad to be helped out.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750835/buttondown-and-buttonup-events-for-android-screen-buttons

Answer (score 2):

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public void onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
        switch(e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                System.out.println(" mouse pressed ");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                System.out.println(" mouse released");
                break;
        }

    }
});
```

you can use MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN case to handle your button color change logic.

hope this will be help to you

if you got it inform me :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation at [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). It shows that button has different states and you can align color on each state. Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector for that like below code

Create selet.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->
<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

Now set the background of button like below

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/selector" />
```